# efficient container control for a WinForms thumbnail PDF navigator

Tags: winforms, navigation, thumbnails

I would like to make a thumbnail PDF navigator for use in a WinForms app. What container would be efficient and appropriate for presenting a vertically arranged set of images, scrollable vertically, where the images are displayed in the order in which they're added, and each can have a listener attached that responds when the image is clicked?

Comment: If it's going to be a one-time adding of those images, why don't you just use a TableLayoutPanel? I assume you've already thought about it, but there should be no particular reason not to use it IMO.

Comment: I haven't worked much with the TLP.   What method would be used to add an Image? I can see how to add a control using the TLP's `Controls.Add(a control)` method.

Comment: I guess you could use an ImageBox as control, but I'm not quite sure if the features will be sufficient enough to fit your needs. You can take a look though.

Comment: `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` would work.  The latter being designed for a uni-direction flow of items.

Comment: The TLP with PictureBox works fairly well, though it's not as quick as I'd like.  The issue with the FLP is that it flows the thumbnails into a second column if necessary, unless I'm overlooking a way to prevent that?

Comment: Yes, the poor functuonallity of the TLP is a well known flaw, but it should not be that big of a problem if you need to load data only one time. Re-formatting from that point on would be a pain in the a*s tho :D